# TTLauncherView causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS (?) When switching back and forth between views several times

Tags: iphone, three20

I have three layered TTLauncherViewControllers that I trigger using the url:
"tt://launcher/{number}" ... the class then checks the number and based on that displays a different launcher view. For instance from the home screen you can click "Team" and a new launcher view pops up with all the team members.

For some reason if I click something and go back and forth it gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS ... which I cannot figure out. Any ideas on why this may be?

Edit: Here is a stack trace:

## 4  0x93f2afda in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler

## 5  0x028e3333 in _objc_terminate

## 6  0x93f2917a in _*cxxabiv1::*_terminate

## 7  0x93f291ba in std::terminate

## 8  0x93f292b8 in __cxa_throw

## 9  0x028e3481 in objc_exception_throw

## 10 0x027956ab in -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]

## 11 0x027052b6 in ***forwarding***

## 12 0x02704e72 in **forwarding_prep_0_**

## 13 0x005e983f in -[UIViewController _containsFirstResponder]

## 14 0x005fa906 in -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didStartTransition:]

## 15 0x0078023e in -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:]

## 16 0x0077fbbf in -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:]

## 17 0x005f3ccd in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded]

## 18 0x00710b55 in -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews]

## 19 0x00154481 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers]

## 20 0x001541b1 in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded

## 21 0x0014d2e0 in CA::Context::commit_transaction

## 22 0x0014d040 in CA::Transaction::commit

## 23 0x0017debb in CA::Transaction::observer_callback

## 24 0x02774f4b in **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION**

## 25 0x02709b27 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers

## 26 0x026d2ce7 in __CFRunLoopRun

## 27 0x026d2350 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific

## 28 0x026d2271 in CFRunLoopRunInMode

## 29 0x031b600c in GSEventRunModal

## 30 0x031b60d1 in GSEventRun

Comment: I have the same problem ! The error has no more details than the EXC_BAD_ACCESS and seems quite random, I dont have it always at the same time of the execution. I have tried adding some pool in my pieces of code to manage Autorelease better but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a memory leak somewhere, either in Three20 or in your code. Are you certain that you're retaining everything as you should be?